# Why am I getting: Failed to parse date field [message.details.message.keyword] with format [strict_date_optional_time] on Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

**Hello!**

**On Kibana, I'm getting this error:**
[essql] > Unexpected error from Elasticsearch: illegal_argument_exception - failed to parse date field [message.details.message.keyword] with format [strict_date_optional_time]

**on this query:**

```
SELECT LAST("UpdateDate"),
CASE WHEN LAST("message.stage.stageMessage") = 'Pending' THEN 'Pending :yellow_circle:'
WHEN LAST("message.stage.stageMessage") = 'GetData' THEN 'Processing :yellow_circle:'
WHEN LAST("message.stage.stageMessage") = 'AdaptAndSave' THEN 'Processing :yellow_circle:'
WHEN LAST("message.stage.stageMessage") = 'Concluded' THEN 'Concluded :green_circle:'
WHEN LAST("message.stage.stageMessage") = 'Failed' THEN 'Failed :red_circle:'
ELSE 'Suspended :x:'
END AS MessageStage ,
FORMAT(LAST("BeginDate"), 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm') as CurrentDate,
LAST("BeginDate"),
LAST("message.groupIntegrationId") AS GroupIntegration,
CASE WHEN LAST("message.groupIntegrationId") IS NULL THEN '____________________________'
ELSE LEFT(LAST("message.groupIntegrationId"), 23)
END AS GroupIntegrationTrimmed,
LAST("BeginDate"),
CASE WHEN LAST("message.success") IS NULL THEN '0'
ELSE CAST(LAST("message.success") AS keyword)
END AS Success,
LAST("BeginDate"),
CASE WHEN LAST("message.errors") IS NULL THEN '0'
ELSE CAST(LAST("message.errors") AS keyword)
END AS Errors
FROM "rabbitmq_integrationrequests_release" WHERE "message.integrationType" = 'ProductVariants' AND "host.assembly" = 'Omnium.CPRDSIT.Services.API' GROUP BY "UpdateDate", "message.groupIntegrationId","message.stage.stageCode" ORDER BY "UpdateDate" DESC, "message.stage.stageCode" DESC LIMIT 1
```

**My data is coming from `logstash`, and the data that comes in the field `message.details.message` is text (should not be interpreted as a date), in this case:**

The entity Product with the id BA8A596F-A90F-43C8-A933-E5624F5CE282 is not integrated in the platform with the id 45B53EBF-43B9-4482-AF47-6EB49F81B8B0.
at Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain.Services.ProductsVariants.Integration.ProductVariantIntegrationService.SetProductVariantsAsync(ProductVariants pProductVariants, Platform pPlatform, ISitooProductGateway pSitooGateway) in /src/Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain/Services/ProductsVariants/Integration/ProductVariantIntegrationService.cs:line 137,
The entity Product with the id BA8A596F-A90F-43C8-A933-E5624F5CE282 is not integrated in the platform with the id 45B53EBF-43B9-4482-AF47-6EB49F81B8B0.
at Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain.Services.ProductsVariants.Integration.ProductVariantIntegrationService.SetProductVariantsAsync(ProductVariants pProductVariants, Platform pPlatform, ISitooProductGateway pSitooGateway) in /src/Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain/Services/ProductsVariants/Integration/ProductVariantIntegrationService.cs:line 137,
The entity Product with the id 0967FEAD-1757-47AE-92C8-3F2DC989B155 is not integrated in the platform with the id 45B53EBF-43B9-4482-AF47-6EB49F81B8B0.
at Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain.Services.ProductsVariants.Integration.ProductVariantIntegrationService.SetProductVariantsAsync(ProductVariants pProductVariants, Platform pPlatform, ISitooProductGateway pSitooGateway) in /src/Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain/Services/ProductsVariants/Integration/ProductVariantIntegrationService.cs:line 137,
The entity Product with the id E5CB474B-CFF6-423C-9AB5-910BC8C19E72 is not integrated in the platform with the id 45B53EBF-43B9-4482-AF47-6EB49F81B8B0.
at Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain.Services.ProductsVariants.Integration.ProductVariantIntegrationService.SetProductVariantsAsync(ProductVariants pProductVariants, Platform pPlatform, ISitooProductGateway pSitooGateway) in /src/Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain/Services/ProductsVariants/Integration/ProductVariantIntegrationService.cs:line 137,
The entity Product with the id CDC66467-B1CB-4845-B74E-05DF335ABFAA is not integrated in the platform with the id 45B53EBF-43B9-4482-AF47-6EB49F81B8B0.
at Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain.Services.ProductsVariants.Integration.ProductVariantIntegrationService.SetProductVariantsAsync(ProductVariants pProductVariants, Platform pPlatform, ISitooProductGateway pSitooGateway) in /src/Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain/Services/ProductsVariants/Integration/ProductVariantIntegrationService.cs:line 137,
The entity Product with the id BA8A596F-A90F-43C8-A933-E5624F5CE282 is not integrated in the platform with the id 45B53EBF-43B9-4482-AF47-6EB49F81B8B0.
at Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain.Services.ProductsVariants.Integration.ProductVariantIntegrationService.SetProductVariantsAsync(ProductVariants pProductVariants, Platform pPlatform, ISitooProductGateway pSitooGateway) in /src/Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain/Services/ProductsVariants/Integration/ProductVariantIntegrationService.cs:line 137,
The entity Product with the id 2F7B0353-CD1C-407F-9D52-C7C5FEE6AA2B is not integrated in the platform with the id 45B53EBF-43B9-4482-AF47-6EB49F81B8B0.
at Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain.Services.ProductsVariants.Integration.ProductVariantIntegrationService.SetProductVariantsAsync(ProductVariants pProductVariants, Platform pPlatform, ISitooProductGateway pSitooGateway) in /src/Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain/Services/ProductsVariants/Integration/ProductVariantIntegrationService.cs:line 137,
The entity Product with the id 930D0480-D5A3-4A62-8176-976EDD6BFB0A is not integrated in the platform with the id 45B53EBF-43B9-4482-AF47-6EB49F81B8B0.
at Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain.Services.ProductsVariants.Integration.ProductVariantIntegrationService.SetProductVariantsAsync(ProductVariants pProductVariants, Platform pPlatform, ISitooProductGateway pSitooGateway) in /src/Omnium.CPRDSIT.Business.Domain/Services/ProductsVariants/Integration/ProductVariantIntegrationService.cs:line 137,

**I don't understand why the field .keyword tries to be parsed as a strict_date_optional and why it even matters since the query does not query for that field.**

Another piece of information that could be relevant is that on Discover, the JSON of the document has this:
`"_ignored": [ "message.details.message.keyword" ],`

I've tried to disable Dynamic mapping, but the error persists.

Can someone assist with this issue?

If you need more information please ask!

Thanks in advance.